# Image anotation (Highlighting parts of an image, Scrubbing an image) using Javascript

Tags: javascript, image-manipulation

We are working on an application and would like users to annotate an image. By annotation I mean, the ability to highlight parts of an image. Once the image is highlighted, and submit is clicked, the highlighted attributes (color, area highlighted) are submitted to the server to be stored in database.

Is this possible using javascript?

Comment: [jQuery annotations plugin](http://www.flipbit.co.uk/jquery-image-annotation.html)

Answer (score 0):

yes. you'll have to store the annotation information separately from the image and then overlay the annotations on the image element when you want to view them again. you'll also have to write your own javascript user interface for selecting colors, drawing regions, etc.